# How to instrument invokedynamic and scalac 2.12 output code with JDI

Tags: scala, jvm, instrumentation, jdi, invokedynamic

I want to instrument ScalaCheck compiled with/for scala 2.12, using JDI.

By running `javap` I have concluded that scalac 2.12.x emits invokedynamic instructions (for some values of x) where scala 2.11 used to generate inner classes, in particular for nested methods/functions.

This presents a challenge, since for performance reasons I would like to set and unset breakpoints on some particular nested functions (`result(x: T)` in `Prop.forAllShrink`, to be particular).

Is it possible to instrument `invokedynamic` code with JDI? If so, how?

I'm new to `invokedynamic` and unclear about how that mechanism works. My understanding is that your code (the code emitted by scalac in my example) makes a linking decision at every `invokedynamic` invocation, except that for performance reasons this decision is cached based on a user-specifiable criterion. However, no run-time code generation is performed. This suggests that in principle `invokedynamic` code should be instrumentable.

I also saw a scary name in some scalac output: `deserializeLambda`. I'm not quite sure what it entails, but I don't think it means I'm going to have an easy time.

Comment: What's the bootstrap method for that callsite? Can you give me an example? (If the bootstrap method is `java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory`, then invoking the lambda will just call a private method - usually one that is given as bootstrap argument.

Comment: I’m struggling with the concept of setting breakpoints “for performance reasons”. Besides that, to add to Johannes Kuhn’s comment, when you assume that “no run-time code generation is performed”, the `invokedynamic` must get linked to an existing method, even when the bootstrap method differs from `LambdaMetafactory`. So you can simply set breakpoints in those target methods.

Comment: Oh, uh, I misspoke. I want to set two breakpoints, such that I can single-step from one to the other, then continue from the second back to the first. The second breakpoint doesn't necessarily have to be a breakpoint, so long as it's a detectable location. Preferably it's stable across ScalaCheck versions, although that's inherently up to what the ScalaCheck people publish. (It's the not-single-stepping from the second location back to the first where the performance gain lies.)

Comment: The solution remains the same. Identify the already existing methods that will get linked and set the break points there.

Comment: I think in retrospect I was chasing a red herring: invokedynamic wasn't preventing me from doing things; the method I was looking for had been inlined, and I had jumped* to the conclusion that it was hidden behind invokedynamic stuff. (*) in my defense, the jump was very natural to make: invokedynamic was a big and very visible difference.